# How to find the wavefunction that solves an infinite square well with a delta function well in the middle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

Solutions for the wavefunction in an infinite square well with a delta function *barrier* in the middle are easily found online (see [here](http://physicspages.com/2012/08/21/infinite-square-well-with-delta-function-barrier/) for an example).  I am wondering what the wavefunction is for an infinite square well with a delta function *well* in the middle.  The setup is the bottom of the infinite square well is defined to be zero energy. I realize that there will be two situations, one where the particle's energy is less than zero and will therefore be bound to the delta function well and one where the particle's energy is greater than zero and is bound to the infinite square well.  What are the wavefunctions for these two situations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider an infinite square with free region $[0, L]$.  Place a delta function potential at $L/2$ with strength $\alpha$.  Then, Schrödinger's equation is

$$E\psi = -\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\frac{\partial^{2}\psi}{\partial x ^{2}} + \alpha \delta(x- \frac{L}{2})\psi$$

First, note that the delta function is zero everywhere except at the center, which means that the energy eigenstates everywhere else are given by $\psi = A \sin (kx + \phi)$.  Furthermore, we know that $\psi(0) = \psi(L) = 0$.  Thus, we know that on the left hand side of the delta, we have $\phi = 0$, and on the right hand side, we have $\phi = - kL$.  Thus, for $0<x<L/2$, we have $\psi = A \sin(kx)$, while for $L/2 < x < L$, we have $\psi = B \sin (k(x-L))$.  The wave function must be continuous at $L/2$, so this guarantees that $A=-B$.

We can derive a restriction on $k$ by integrating Schrödinger's equation over an arbitrarily small region around $x = L/2$.  Since the wave function is continuous, the left hand side drops off, and we're left with:

$$0 = -\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}(\psi^{\prime}_{+} - \psi{\prime}_{-}) + \alpha\psi(L/2)$$

Or, more concretely,

$$\psi^{\prime}_{+} = \frac{2m\alpha}{\hbar^{2}}\psi(L/2) + \psi^{\prime}_{-} $$

Taking the derivative and substituting, we find:

$$-Ak\cos(kL/2) = \frac{2m\alpha}{\hbar^{2}}A\sin(kL/2)+Ak\cos(kL/2)$$

Finally, this gives us the transcendental equation

$$\tan(kL/2) = - \frac{\hbar^{2}k}{m\alpha}$$

Noting that we still have, as in the finite square well case, $E = \frac{\hbar^{2}k^{2}}{2m}$, all solutions have $E > 0$, irrespective of the sign of $\alpha$, although simple graphing shows that there are infinite numbers of solutions to this equation, independent of the sign of $\alpha$ (though the sign of and value of $\alpha$ will shift where those solutions are quite dramatically).

Comment: I'm sure we can still have E<0, the wavefunction will just have a different form than what you proposed here.

Comment: @Joshua: what I gave here was a complete eigenbasis of the Hilbert space.  All square integrable functions on $[0,L]$ can be expressed as a sum of these functions.

Comment: @Jerry Schimer:
transcendental equation should be $tan(kL/2$) = - $\dfrac{\hbar^2k}{m\alpha}$ Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer I have read your answer, and I think that it's very interesting. But can we have an explicit expression for the energy levels?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer There is also a non-trivial solution for E=0 which exists only under a certain condtion for a(the "height" of the delta)

Comment: There is an assumption that E > 0, but can't we also look for solutions with E < 0, in which case the form of $\psi$ changes?

Comment: In the answer, he considered a delta barrier, not delta well, so there is no wavefunction for E<0? @Frank

Comment: You have taken sine function with a phase instead of superposition of sine and cosine function, are there any particular cases in which we can do this, or we can do this always? @JerrySchirmer

Comment: @sawankt: The sine is chosen to deal with the boundary conditions at $x=0$ and $x=L$,  If you did a combination of sine or cosine, you could use trig identities to reduce it to sine with a phase, and then you'd end up choosing the phase to satisfy the boundary conditions, and it would be equivalent.