# Bounded energy states for the infinite well with delta potential at origin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, schroedinger-equation

So I have this potential
$$ V(x) = \begin{cases}
-a\delta(x) & -b < x < b \\
\infty & |x| \geq b
\end{cases}
$$
Solving the time independent Schrödinger Equation for bound energy states $(E<0)$ gave me:
$$
\psi_1(x) = Ae^{kx} + Be^{-kx}\mbox{,   }-b<x<0 \\
\psi_2(x) = Ce^{kx} + De^{-kx}\mbox{, }0<x<b
$$
Where $k=\sqrt{\frac{-2mE}{\hbar^2}}$ and $\psi(x) = 0$ elsewhere. Then, I also got these boundaries conditions:

$$
\psi_1(x\rightarrow 0) = \psi_2(x\rightarrow 0) <=> A + B = C+D \tag{1}
$$
$$
\frac{d\psi_2}{dx}\Big|_{\epsilon⁺} - \frac{d\psi_1}{dx}\Big|_{\epsilon⁻} = \frac{2m} {\hbar^2}\int_{\epsilon^-}^{\epsilon^+}dx\delta(x)\psi(x) <=> K(C-D-A+B) = \frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\psi(0) \tag{2}
$$
$$
\psi(b) = \psi_2(b) = Ce^{kb} + De^{-kb} = 0 \tag{3}
$$
$$
\psi(-b) = \psi_1(-b) = Ae^{-kb} + Be^{kb} = 0 \tag{4}
$$
From these, I got $A=D$ and $B=C$, where $B=-Ae^{-2kb}$. Now, when I plugged these into (2), I got
$$
tanh(kb) = -\frac{\hbar^2k}{m}
$$
where, if I let $z = kb$, I have
$$
tanh(z) = -\frac{\hbar^2z}{mb}
$$
for which only $z = 0$ is a solution, implying that $k=0$ and $\psi_1(x)=\psi_2(x)=0$. What  did I miss? I can't find where I'm messing up.

Edit: I missed the $-a$ of the potential. Plugging it in, I get this final equation:
$$
tanhkb = \frac{k\hbar^2}{ma}
$$
which has a solution under a constraint. If we let $z=kb$:
$$
tanhz = \frac{\hbar^2}{mab}z
$$
then we have a solution if $\frac{\hbar^2}{mb}<a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your analysis is correct in that there are no nontrivial eigenstates with $E \leq 0$. See this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80120/37496

However because of the infinite potential well we only need $E < \infty$ for bound states, so even positive energy states will be bound states. This is the same as in the case of the infinite square well with no delta potential, where all of the eigenstates are bound states with positive energy.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that!