# An interesting (but standard for sure) potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

Consider the potential well with $$U(x) = \begin{cases}-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{m}\kappa_{0}\delta(x), & |x|<a\\+\infty, & |x|\geq a\end{cases}$$
I want to find $E_{n}$. First of all, $U(x)$ is even, can this be useful? What conclusion can one draw from this? Anyway, I started with $$\psi''(x) - \kappa^2\psi(x) = 0$$ when $x\in (-a,a)$. It seems that only $\kappa$ of the form $\kappa = \tilde{\kappa}i,\;\tilde{\kappa}\in\mathbb{R}$ will work. Integrating the equation from $-\varepsilon$ to $\varepsilon$ and then sending $\varepsilon$ to zero, one can obtain $$\psi'(+0) - \psi'(-0) = -2\kappa_{0}\psi(0)\;\tag{*}$$ Suppose that $$\psi(x) = \begin{cases}A\cos(\kappa x) + B\sin(\kappa x),\;x\in(-a,0)\\\tilde{A}\cos(\kappa x) + \tilde{B}\sin(\kappa x),\;x\in(0,a)\end{cases}$$ From continuity of $\psi$ it follows that $A=\tilde{A}$, also, since $\psi$ is zero at $\pm a$, then $(\tilde{B} + B)\sin(3\kappa a) = 0$. Now we use (*) to obtain $$\kappa(\tilde{B} - B) = -2\kappa_{0}A$$ So, one value of $\kappa$ we can get from $\tilde{B} = -B$ and normalization condition. All others we get from $\sin(3\kappa a) = 0$, and $\kappa^2 = \frac{2m}{\hbar^2}|E|$. Am I right? I feel like I made some mistakes from the start. I mean, is this really a valid approach to such a problem? If it is not, please, give a hint

Comment: [Due diligence](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80106/how-to-find-the-wavefunction-that-solves-an-infinite-square-well-with-a-delta-fu) and [linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/559863/bounded-energy-states-for-the-infinite-well-with-delta-potential-at-origin?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

I’ll assume for simplicity that $m=\hbar=a=1$ up to a change if units. The eigenvalue problem is therefore:
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\psi’’-\kappa_0\delta\psi=E\psi
$$

For your first question, the even potential is useful since spatial parity commutes with the Hamiltonian. You can therefore find a simultaneously diagonal basis. In practice, you just need to assume that your wave functions are even or odd. In the even case, $\psi$ is of the form:
$$
\psi=A\sin(k(1-|x|))
$$
with $E=\frac{k^2}{2}$. The condition at the origin gives:
$$
k\cos k=\kappa_0 \sin k
$$
Note that for $\kappa_0>1$, you’ll have an extra pure imaginary solution for $k$ representing a bound state.

In the odd case, $\psi$ is of the form:
$$
\psi=A\sin(kx)
$$
with $E=\frac{k^2}{2}$. The boundary condition at $x=\pm 1$ gives:
$$
\sin(k)=0
$$

From this you can deduce the discrete spectrum of allowed $k$ and the corresponding energies.

I don’t quite follow your computation, especially how a factor $3$ pops in the argument of the $\sin$.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, $U(x)$ is even, can this be useful?
> What conclusion can one draw from this?

Yes, it is useful.
From this you can conclude: All solutions $\psi(x)$ are either even or odd.
This enables you to write down the solutions immediately.

The odd solutions must look like this (without a $\cos$ term):
$$\psi(x) = \begin{cases}
B\sin(\kappa x),\quad x\in(-a,0) \\
B\sin(\kappa x),\quad x\in(0,a)
\end{cases}$$

And the even solutions must look like this:
$$\psi(x) = \begin{cases}
A\cos(\kappa x) + B\sin(\kappa x),\quad x\in(-a,0) \\
A\cos(\kappa x) - B\sin(\kappa x),\quad x\in(0,a)
\end{cases}$$
Then you can find a relation between $A$ and $B$
like you already did in your question.